# How to allocate memory for an array of structs, then pass that array to a function, which populates the array in C

Tags: c

I'm writing a program where I am trying to allocate memory for an array of structs in the main then pass the array to a function which reads data in from a file, creates the structs and populates the array with the structs created.

For some reason this piece of code is only allocating enough memory for 7 elements in the array;

```
int assets_size = count_lines("rescue_assets.txt");
asset *assets;
assets = (asset*)malloc(sizeof(asset)*assets_size);
```

The amount of lines in the file are 37 and the count_lines method works, as it is tested in the main.

Below is the complete code for the main;

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int i;
    int assets_size = count_lines("rescue_assets.txt");
    asset *assets;
    assets = (asset*)malloc(sizeof(asset)*assets_size);
    ship ships[100];

    printf("%d\n", assets_size);

    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(assets));

    read_data(assets, ships);

    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(assets));

    for (i=0; i<sizeof(assets)-1; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", assets[i].deployment_time);
    }
    free(assets);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Below is the relevant code for the function read_data;

```
void read_data(asset *assets, ship ships[]) {
int max_assets;
int max_ships;
FILE *asset_file_ptr;
FILE *ship_file_ptr;
int count = 0;
int file_max = 100;
char asset_file[file_max];
char ship_file[file_max];

asset_file_ptr = fopen("rescue_assets.txt", "r");

if (asset_file_ptr == NULL) {
   printf("The asset file could not be opened."); 
   exit(0);       
}
else {
    char callsign[file_max];
    char type;
    char placename[file_max];
    double base_longitude;
    double base_latitude;
    double speed;
    int deployment_time;
    int service_time; 

    while (fscanf(asset_file_ptr, "%s %c %s %lf %lf %lf %d %d", callsign, &type,    placename, &base_longitude, &base_latitude, &speed, &deployment_time, &service_time)!= EOF) {
        asset* new_asset = malloc(sizeof(asset));
        new_asset->callsign = callsign;
        new_asset->type = type;
        new_asset->placename = placename;
        new_asset->base_longitude = base_longitude;
        new_asset->base_latitude = base_latitude;
        new_asset->speed = speed;
        new_asset->deployment_time = deployment_time;
        new_asset->service_time = service_time;

        assets[count] = *new_asset;
        count++;
    }
}
fclose(asset_file_ptr);

}
```

Here is the output I get from running the main;

37
8
8
600
180
180
818
180
600

the program first prints out the assets_size, which is 37.
then it prints out the size of the assets array, which should be 37, but is 8.
same again.
It then prints out the deployment time of all the assets that have been populated in to the array, which is only 7.

Please can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure, that it's not because fscanf is returning EOF? Did you check, that the file REALLY has 37 lines?

Comment: Try to Change `assets = (asset*)malloc(sizeof(asset)*assets_size)` with `assets = malloc(sizeof(asset*) * assets_size + 1)`

Comment: Also, it seems to me, like you've got a memory leak in your code. You're allocating memory for `new_asset`, pass the content 'by value' into the array, which copies the struct, but then you don't free the preallocated object. Either use a local variable of type  `asset` or call `free` at the end of your while loop.

Comment: @Gabson That's not a good idea. The way I understand it, he wants an array of actual variables and not an array of pointers.

Comment: My bad misunderstanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your for loop in main to print the deployment times, `sizeof(assets)` does not give you the length of the array, there is no way to get the length of an array only pointed to by a simple pointer. `sizeof(assets)` gives you the size of a pointer in chars, which is 8 as you're apparently working on a 64 bit platform. Simply run from 0 up to `asset_size`.

And why are you mallocing a new struct in `read_data` for each asset, just write directly into the asset array.

In main do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size_assets; ++i)
    printf("%d\n", assets[i].deployment_time);
```

In read_data do:

```
asset* asset_p = assets;
while (fscanf(...) != EOF) {
    asset_p->field = data;
    ...
    ++asset_p;
}
```

or alternatively:

```
int i = 0;
while (fscanf(...) != EOF) {
    assets[i].field = data;
    ...
    ++i;
}
```

or yet alternatively:

```
for (int i = 0; fscanf(...) != EOF; ++i) {
    assets[i].field = data;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ah, good catch. I didn't even look there yet. You are of course correct. It's an output problem before anything else.